# Python internal string format indexing with range

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I would like to use segment of the same string in a formatted string.

```python
input_string = 'abcdefhijk'
result_string = "A's name is abcd-defh; he does hijk"
```

The intuitive solution is

```python
"A's name is {0[0:4]}-{0{[3:7]}; he does {0[6:10]}".format(input_string)
```

And this obviously doesn't work.
What works is the round-about way

```python
"A's name is {0}-{1}; he does {2}".format(input_string[0:4], input_string[3:7], input_string[6:10])
```

Is there any easy way to specify the index range in the formatting string?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.6, you can make a similar construct to your "intuitive solution" with [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
>>> input_string = 'abcdefhijk'
>>> f"A's name is {input_string[0:4]}-{input_string[3:7]}; he does {input_string[6:10]}"
"A's name is abcd-defh; he does hijk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below

```
result_string = "A's name is %s-%s; he does %s" %(input_string[:4], input_string[3:7], input_string[6:10])
```